# At what length should horizontal strips of tape be applied to joints in between drywall cornerbeads?

Tags: drywall

If one's taping drywall in between two corner beads, like a door for example, and there's multiple horizontal seams in between, should he attempt to tape those horizontal sections even if it meant either,

A) putting paper under the corner beads
Or B) applying very short strips of tape

My understanding is that A should always be avoided.

Here is an example where the gap is larger, and I would assume you'd always apply tape:

[image]

Here's what I'm working with, where the gap would only be ~2-3" between the corner beads (blue). A maybe only half an inch on the side (red).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is as much art as science.  What I would do in the situation of your second picture is put tape *between* the corner beads, not under them.  I'll be filling the space between the beads entirely with compound, not feathering, using the beads as a level.  So I would try not to create high points by putting tape under the beads, that would require me to feather vertically.   I'm not sure that's the *best* technique, but it's easier IMO and works for me.

Answer (score 1):

In the instances that you have pictured, I prefer to use mesh tape on the seams. Then install the corner bead.

Comment: So on both directions (red and blue)? And what's the thought process? Larger seems -> use mesh tape because, stronger? Less likely to bubble? Easier to apply? I think I've seen mesh be recommend for larger seams before, but not sure exactly why. Edit: I think get it, you apply mesh vertically, and it gives support + helps level mud between beads

Comment: @Jay613, hit it better than me.  This is more art than science.  I never put great scientific thought into the how or why or what of applying tape.  I just go on what technique works for me after 50 years of practice.   Others may have very different techniques.  I never heard any hard and fast rules, other than  make sure it doesn't look crappy.

Comment: Thanks, now that I'm actually in the process of putting it up, I see exactly what you mean about it being more art than science.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with A. Applying tape under bead. Especially with tapered drywall edges. Make sure to v back the fuzzy paper before taping on non tapered drywall edges. You can install paper tape horizontally in these situations, say about a 4" piece works well.

For mud on bead, I prefer prefilling recessed joints and allowing it to dry before installation, it goes on straighter that way.

Comment: That makes sense. Is "don't put tape under tape" mainly just applicable to paper tape, in order to avoid bubbling at the intersections of seems? Rather than corner beads mesh tape around patches that are good to be filled?

Comment: I've never heard that rule. As long as you make sure there is a thin layer of mud under the tape it should work.  I have yet to see a mesh tape job bedded in standard joint compound that hasn't cracked. Mesh tape is supposed to be used with setting type joint compound only.

Comment: On a pro level, you always run butt seams first, then tapered seams that overlap the butt seams. Some drywallers like to run all the butt seams first and let them dry down before they run the tapered. I prefer doing it all together.